# Installing MySQL Python on Mac OS X

Tags: python, mysql, macos

Long story short, when I write the following:

```
sudo easy_install MySQL-python
```

I get the error

> EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

All right, so there are plenty of threads and the like on how to fix that, so I run this code:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Then I rerun my sudo code:

```
sudo easy_install MySQL-python
```

Then I get the following error.

> Setup script exited with error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

Google/Stack Overflow that, and I am told to download a [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) package which I did the other day, 200 MB's or there-abouts and still no fix.

At this point I am lost, they say insanity is doing the same thing over and over while expecting a different result. Well, I've continually run the aforementioned code expecting a different result, so I'm not to far away from going insane.

At this point in my Python career, I am new to this, but I am willing to try pretty much anything to get this up and running.

If it helps I am officially running, Mac OS X 10.7.5, and I do have [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP) installed (is that an issue?)

Also, the other day when I was trying all of this for the first time I installed (reinstalled?) MySQL, so I'm really in a tough spot at this point.

Is there a fix?

I've racked my brain, searched Google, read Stack Overflow, and spent hours trying to figure this out to no avail.

Comment: can you post the output of `gcc` command on the terminal?

Comment: When I run `gcc` I get the following: i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 no input files

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Another option is to use [pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) it is a pure Python client connection to MySQL so you don't have to mess around with compiling, a good exercise, but it can be frustrating if you are just trying to get something done.   pymysql follows the same API as MySQLdb, it can essentially be used as a drop in replacement.

Also, it used to be that MySQLdb, did not work with Python 3, but this may have changed, pymysql didn't have that problem which also induced me to switch, this may have changed though.   pymysql can be slower than MySQLdb but you'll have to see if you notice that, it is also under a different license (MIT for pymysql, GPL for MySQLdb)

Comment: Im not sure if this is a bandaid type solution, but it worked! I was able to easily install pymysql and connect to my DB/run commands without issue. In the future im still interested in learning how to get MySQL up and running but for now this should do the trick.

Thanks Paul!

Comment: @Peter: Glad it helped, MySQLdb is just tricky to install because of the C interface (but this does make it faster).   If you switch to MySQLdb in the future though, you won't have to change much in your Python code, all the calls to cursors and connections should be identical to pymysql, you just have to import someting else.

Comment: This worked wonderfully for me, much easier that the old JDBS ODBC driver dance

Comment: MySQLdb has been forked into the mysqlclient-python project (https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) to support Python 3+

Comment: If anyone may be able to help, I'm having trouble using pymysql: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145845/cannot-make-remote-connection-with-pymysql-pymysql-err-internalerror-packet-se

Answer (score 57):

Here's what I would install, especially if you want to use [homebrew](http://brew.sh):

- XCode and the command line tools (as suggested by @7stud, @kjti)
- Install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)
- `brew install mysql-connector-c`
- `pip install mysql-python`

Comment: Getting error on `pip install mysql-python` : `error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: Permission denied`

Comment: I use a homebrew python installation, and on my machine the Python packages live in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`, which are writeable for me ([homebrew doesn't want to use sudo](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad-)). You might find [Homebrew and Python](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-and-Python.md) a good read, too. If you just want to use the system python, `sudo pip install...` might do the trick.

Comment: I get the following error -  `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1..`

Comment: Fails with `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/xr/4nbrl6_n67ggkm4v6zkk8v_nq0kng2/T/pip-install-hxjvbd/mysql-python/`. I am using Python 3.6.4

Comment: Python 3 is not yet supported by `mysql-python`: > MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.4 through 2.7 are currently supported. Python-3.0 will be supported in a future release. PyPy is supported. [source](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/)

Answer (score 13):

**For Python 3+** the `mysql-python` library is broken. Instead, use the [mysqlclient library](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python). `Install with: pip install mysqlclient`

It is a fork of mysql-python (*also known as MySQLdb*) that supports Python 3+

This library talks to the MySQL client's C-interface, and is faster than the pure-python pymysql libray.

**Note**: you will need the mysql-developer tools installed. An easy way to do this on a Mac is to run

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

to delegate this task to homebrew. If you are on linux, you can install these via the instructions at the [mysqlclient github page](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python).

Comment: This was a huge help and solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Successful in 2019 with macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra) using Ansible's (v2.8.5)  mysql_db module, Python 3.7.5, 10.4.6-MariaDB.  I *didn't* need the brew mysql-connector-c formula.

Answer (score 12):

Install mysql via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), then you can install mysql python via pip.

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

It works for me.

Comment: Worked for me.  Also found this suggestion at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459386/mac-os-x-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found

Comment: Says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'` on python 3.6.5

Answer (score 5):

I am using OSX -v **10.10.4**. The solution above is a [quick & easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920020/3276790).

Happening OSX does not have the connection library by default.

First you should install the connector:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

Then install with pip mysql

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: You should install first pip if you don't have it yet. Pip it's the package manager of Python and it may be not installed although you already have Python in your Mac.

Comment: I get the following error - `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1.. `

Answer (score 3):

**To install PyMySQL**

install pip => `sudo easy_install pip`

install PyMySQL=> `sudo easy_install-3.7 pymysql`

terminal command to check whether installed or not => `pip3 list`

or

install PyMySQL=> `sudo pip install PyMySQL`

terminal command to check whether installed or not => `pip3 list`

**MySQL**

The macOS Sierra Public Beta’s didn’t play well with MySQL 5.7.x, but these issues are now resolved by using MySQL 5.7.16

MySQL doesn’t come pre-loaded with macOS Sierra and needs to be dowloaded from the MySQL site.

( https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)
The latest version of **MySQL 5.7.16** does work with the public release of macOS.

If you already have MySQL 5.7 and you have upgraded OS from El Capitan to Sierra I expect that to be ok, but will be interested if anyone comments on that.

Use the **Mac OS X 10.11 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive version** (works on macOS Sierra).

If you are upgrading from a previous OSX and have an older MySQL version you do not have to update it. One thing with MySQL upgrades always take a data dump of your database in case things go south and before you upgrade to macOS Sierra make sure your MySQL Server is **not** running.

When downloading you don’t have to sign up, look for ***» No thanks, just take me to the downloads!***  – go straight to the download mirrors and download the software from a mirror which is closest to you.

Once downloaded open the .dmg and run the installer.

When it is finished installing you get a dialog box with a temporary **mysql root password** – that is a MySQL root password not a macOS admin password, copy and paste it so you can use it. But I have found that the temporary password is pretty much useless so we’ll need to change it straight away.

You are also told:
If you lose this password, please consult the section How to Reset the Root Password in the MySQL reference manual.(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

**Change the MySQL root password**

Note that this is not the same as the root or admin password of macOS – this is a unique password for the **mysql root user**, use one and remember/jot down somewhere what it is.

Stop MySQL

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

**if stop throws permission issue**

Check the error file first.

```
tail -f /usr/local/mysql/data/*.err
```

Do a complete shut down or kill the process. Confirm that no mysql process is running

```
mysqladmin -uroot shutdown
sudo killall mysqld 

ps -ef | grep mysql
```

Give permisiions

```
sudo chown -RL root:mysql /usr/local/mysql
sudo chown -RL mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/mysql/data
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/mysql/data/accountname.local.pid

or Right click->get info and change the permission for 
/usr/local/mysql/data
/usr/local/mysql/data/Pushparajas-MacBook-Pro.local.pid
```

Start mysql

```
sudo mysql.server start
```

Start it in safe mode:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

This will be an ongoing command until the process is finished so **open another shell/terminal window**, and log in with a password which is temporary generated:

```
mysql -u root -p
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass'
```

;
Change the lowercase ‘MyNewPass’ to what you want – and keep the single quotes.

```
\q
```

Start MySQL

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

**Starting MySQL**

You can then start the MySQL server from the System Preferences or via the command line.

Command line start MySQL.

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

To find the MySQL version from the terminal, type at the prompt:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -v -uroot -p
```

This also puts you in to a shell interactive dialogue with mySQL, type \q to exit.

After installation, in order to use mysql commands without typing the full path to the commands you need to add the mysql directory to your shell path, (optional step) this is done in your “.bash_profile” file in your home directory, if you don’t have that file just create it using vi or nano:

```
cd ; nano .bash_profile
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

The first command brings you to your home directory and opens the .bash_profile file or creates a new one if it doesn’t exist, then add in the line above which adds the mysql binary path to commands that you can run. Exit the file with type “control + x” and when prompted save the change by typing “y”. Last thing to do here is to reload the shell for the above to work straight away.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
mysql -v
```

You will get the version number again, just type “q” to exit.

Fix the 2002 MySQL Socket error

Fix the looming 2002 socket error – which is linking where MySQL places the socket and where macOS thinks it should be, MySQL puts it in **/tmp** and macOS looks for it in **/var/mysql** the socket is a type of file that allows mysql client/server communication.

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

**phpMyAdmin**

uncomment below line in **httpd.conf** file

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

First fix the 2002 socket error if you haven’t done so from the MySQL section-

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Download phpMyAdmin, (https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) the zip English package will suit a lot of users, then unzip it and move the folder with its contents into the document root level(~/Sites/) renaming folder to ‘phpmyadmin’.

Make the **config** folder

```
mkdir ~/Sites/phpmyadmin/config
```

Change the permissions

```
chmod o+w ~/Sites/phpmyadmin/config
```

Run the set up in the browser
http://localhost/~username/phpmyadmin/setup/ or http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/

You need to create a new localhost mysql server connection, click **new server**.

Switch to the **Authentication** tab and set the local mysql root user and the password.

Add in the username “root” (maybe already populated, add in the password that you set up earlier for the MySQL root user set up, click on save and you are returned to the previous screen.
(This is not the macOS Admin or root password – it is the MySQL root user).

Make sure you click on save, then a config.inc.php is now in the /config directory of phpmyadmin directory, **move** this file to the root level of /phpmyadmin and then remove the now **empty** /config directory.

**In the latest phpmyadmin, download the config.inc.php and place in phpmyadmin directory.**

If you want to setup new server move config.inc.php to some location and try **http://localhost/~username/phpmyadmin/setup**

Now going to http://localhost/~username/phpmyadmin/ will now allow you to interact with your MySQL databases.

To upgrade phpmyadmin just download the latest version and copy the older ‘**config.inc.php**‘ from the existing directory into the new folder and replace – backup the older one just in case.

**Permissions**

To run a website with no permission issues it is best to set the web root and its contents to be writeable by all, since it’s a local development it shouldn’t be a security issue.

Lets say that you have a site in the **User Sites** folder at the following location **~/Sites/testsite** you would set it to be writeable like so:

```
sudo chmod -R a+w ~/Sites/testsite
```

If you are concerned about security then instead of making it world writeable you can set the owner to be Apache **_www** but when working on files you would have to authenticate more as admin you are “not” the owner, you would do this like so:

```
sudo chown -R _www ~/Sites/testsite
```

This will set the contents recursively to be owned by the Apache user.
If you had the website stored at the **System** level Document root at say **~/Sites/testsite** then it would have to be the latter:

```
sudo chown -R _www ~/Sites/testsite
```

Another easier way to do this if you have a one user workstation is to change the Apache web user from _www to your account.
That’s it! You now have the native AMP stack running on top of macOS Sierra.

Ref Link - https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/#ssu

Answer (score 3):

On Mojave, I ran into errors with finding the SSL libraries, here's what finally worked without having to modify `mysql_config`:

```
sudo pip install MySQL-Python --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
```

Hopefully that will save someone a few hours of heartache

Comment: Works for me on Big Sur. Other ways didnt work for me on Big Sur. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's time to be a big boy and install from source.  Try this:

1) Download the MySQL-python-1.X.X.tar.gz file(by default will go to your Downloads directory)

2) Open a Terminal window and cd to the Downloads directory.

3) Unzip the file you downloaded:

```
~/Downloads$ tar xfvz MySQL-python-1.X.X.tar.gz
```

That will create a directory inside your Downloads directory called MySQL-python

4) cd into the newly created directory.

5) Typically, you just open the file called README or INSTALL and follow the instructions--but generally to install a python module all you do is:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

If you care to look, there should be a file called setup.py inside your newly created MySQL-python directory, and you are invoking that program to install the module.

Also note that this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

is not permanent if you did that on the command line.  You need to put that line in a file called .bashrc in your home directory (~/ or equivalently /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME).  To see if .bashrc already exists(it's a hidden file), issue the command:

```
$ ls -al
```

and look for .bashrc.  If .bashrc doesn't exist, then create it.

Comment: Alright so I went through everything and was great until after 5, wherein again I receive the mysql_config not found error.

Comment: 1) cd to /usr/local/mysql/bin and do $ ls and see if mysql-config is in there.  If it is, then do $ echo $PATH.  If /usr/local/mysql/bin is not in your PATH, then put it in your path inside .bashrc using the export command you posted.  To make sure Terminal is using your new .bashrc type $ source .bashrc, then open another Terminal window and try to install again.

Comment: ...make that $ source ~/.bashrc

Comment: Alright im a little confused but I think we're making some progress I did `cd /usr/local/mysql/bin` and when i ran `ls` I see that mysql_config is listed. I then typed `echo $PATH` and received the following output `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

Now the next noob question, what do I do with that string?

Comment: So you just ignored all the times I told you to either open or create the file ~/.bashrc?

Comment: I've told you twice already. cd to your home directory: $ cd ~, and check for the hidden file named .bashrc: $ ls -al.  If .bashrc exists open it.  If not create it. Then add /usr/local/mysql/bin to your PATH by adding the line: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin to .bashrc.  Your $PATH environment variable is a colon delimited list of all the directories that your mac will search for commands that you issue.  That export command says to assign the old list of directories plus /usr/local/mysql/bin to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: After updating .bashrc, you either have to close all your Terminal windows AND quit Terminal, OR do $ source ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned before me....getting Python to work with MySQL on a Mac is a ?@#$@&%^!! nightmare.

Installed Django framework on Mac OS 10.7.5 initially from the original Django website and when the MySQLdb didn't work, and after many hours googling and trying solutions from SO, I have installed the Django stack from BitNami http://bitnami.com/stack/django

Still, got the issues mentioned above and then some more...

What helped me eventually is what Josh recommends on his blog: http://joshbranchaud.com/blog/2013/02/10/Errors-While-Setting-Up-Django.html

Now Python 2.7 is finally connected to MySQL 5.5

Comment: I feel your pain.  I had so much trouble doing the exact same thing as you once.  I eventually ditched the project.  The other day I had to start using python again with mysql and had instant success (it just worked) with pymysql.  Not sure if it's an option for you.  If it's not, I apologize.  Worth a look though.

Comment: Thanks. I have eventually left Django and moved to Web2Py. What a difference! Easy and fast install, better documentation, great IDE, works with MySQL out of the box, built in web server, debugger, etc. Recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that the `gcc` compiler is not installed on your Mac. It will be installed if you have installed XCode. You will have to download `gcc` complier and install it manually. Follow the below link and download it -

> https://github.com/downloads/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/GCC-10.7-v2.pkg

I once had this problem installing Ruby 1.9 and I had to compile ruby for myself because Mountain Lion wasn't supported at that time. After installing the package, verify the install by the command `gcc`.

Comment: I've got Xcode installed as well as the GCC tool linked above.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64) on Mac OS X 10.11.4 15E65.

You may want to follow the steps below:

- Install homebrew
- Open a terminal and run: brew install mysql-connector-c
- pip install mysql-python

Then the Anaconda will have the mysql-python installed and you can start with MySQLdb then.

Good luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Above all, I can't solve it. But I add file to /usr/local/include solve it.

https://github.com/peterlee0304/MySQL-Python/blob/master/my_config.h

In /usr/local/include, add a my_config.h file.

Then pip install MySQL-Python

Solve it!

Comment: That's great. Maybe you can post the relevant section of the `config.h` file directly here with an indication of the essential addition?

Comment: Yes, I also want to do it. But this comment limits words.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysql-python
```

Answer (score 0):

### the below may be help.

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
CFLAGS =-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/include pip install MySQL-python
brew unlink mysql-connector-c
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer would be much more helpful if you could briefly describe why/when the proposed solution should work.

Comment: @norok2 yeah right, like that has stopped anyone before.

Answer (score 0):

***I used PyMySQL instead and its working fine!***

```
sudo easy_install-3.7 pymysql
```