# MySQLdb AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'commit'

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to connect to and insert into a MySQL database on my machine following [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm) and I am stumped. Everything seems to look good up until the point where the the change is actually committed. I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "write.py", line 18, in <module>
    db.commit()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'commit'
```

I have followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920020/2357169) to install Python on my Mac and my code looks like this:

```
#!usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb as db

try:
    con = db.connect(host='localhost', user='trevor', passwd='pw', db='aqi');

    cur = con.cursor()

    sql_statement = """INSERT INTO aqi(datetime, no2, o3, so2, co, pm10, pm25, aqi, health_range)
                       VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    print sql_statement

    cur.execute(sql_statement, ("some date", 13.2, 53.5, 45.4, 31.1, 31.1, 32.3, 33.4, "healthy"))

    db.commit()

except db.Error, e:

    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

finally:

  if con:
    con.close()
```

I haven't found any reference to this type of error anywhere and it really doesn't make sense. I would really appreciate any help or direction. Thanks!

Comment: note `datetime` is reserve work don't use it as column name, else  use `\``

Comment: thank you @GrijeshChauhan. I appreciate the note. I am still pretty new to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need do connection commit instead of db:

```
con.commit()
```

db is alias for module MySQLdb, con is connection object.