# Error installing mysql-python: library not found for -lssl

Tags: pip, virtualenv, homebrew, mysql-python

I'm having trouble installing mysql-python. Created a new virtualenv and when installing mysql-python... here's the error message:

```
(env)$ pip install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
...

clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.12-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr /local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.so
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Using homebrew, I have installed:

- libressl
- openssl
- openssl@1.1
- mysql

Already tried to `brew link` but brew refuses to do so.

The OS is MacOS Sierra.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved it with these steps:

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql-connector-c
pip install mysql-python
brew unlink mysql-connector-c
brew install mysql
```

Found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920020/576192

Not sure if this is the right way, but this is how I managed to solve it.

Answer (score 43):

You can set ssl library path explicitly.

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: The library installed. However, it fails to run with segmentation fault 11

Comment: Solved my problem.

Comment: Solved my problem as well.

Comment: For more general (if installing openssl through brew): `LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 25):

I tried updating Xcode's CLT, uninstalling `mysql`, checking mysql_config, etc., but had no luck.

I found that running `brew info openssl` shows:

```
...

For compilers to find openssl you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

...
```

Running those two commands, followed by `pip install`, worked for me (in my case when installing `mysqlclient`).

Comment: Thanks, that helped but one should run
"brew info openssl" and not "brew info ssl"

and then I run all "export" commands which helped me successfully run
"pip3 install mysqlclient"

Comment: @FFinn Correct, thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer.

Comment: saved a day. @alstr

Answer (score 11):

I'm able to fix the error by running:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
```

Comment: This worked for me .

Brew states - openssl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides LibreSSL.

Answer (score 8):

I was finally able to fix it by

`xcode-select --install`

I was sure I had already done that... but obviously I hadn't. Definitely worth a shot!

Answer (score 3):

For me on mac, running this command solved the issue

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysqlclient
```

Actually we need to set ssl library path to get this issue fixed.

Comment: Strangely enough this worked for me. I have no idea why but it worked.

Comment: Hi @hafiz-siddiq, there's another answer like yours https://stackoverflow.com/a/46888783/2247042, this doesn't add value.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me by doing this

```
$ brew uninstall mysql
$ brew install mysql-connector-c
$ brew unlink mysql-connector-c
$ brew install mysql
$ pip install mysql-python
```

Which is a slightly altered version of the recipe above (note: `pip install` at the end!)

Comment: This also fixes the error I received `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
`   This fixes the issue for this substitution for the last line `pip3 install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install `mysql-python`, I suggest you to install `mysqlclient` instead. The authors of these two modules are the same. By far, the authors all turn to keep maintaining [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python). `mysqlclient` supports both Python 2 and Python 3. And you can use the same codes like `mysql-python`. Blew is my installation solution for you.

```
$ brew info openssl
$ brew unlink mysql-connector-c
$ brew install mysql
$ brew link --overwrite mysql-connector-c
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

If there is an error before `pip install mysqlclient`. Please fix it according to [methane's answer](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/169#issuecomment-299778504).
And run `pip install mysqlclient` again.

Answer (score 1):

Or download and install .dmg from the MySQL dev site: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=467834

Comment: This works too but, it also messes with me that there are 3 ways you can install `mysql` on your mac.  `brew` `pip` and also the `dmg` file.  and if you have more than just one, it becomes a nightmare with odd errors or breaking the DMG install by using `pip` or `brew`.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are installing MySQL v5.7 with Brew

Uninstall `mysql-connector-c`

```
$ brew uninstall mysql-connector-c
```

Install specific version, very likely you need to uninstall other installed versions

```
$ brew install mysql@5.7
```

You will need to add it to the `PATH`, since this is 'keg-only' formulae, this is printed after it is installed

```
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Replace `~/.zshrc` with the appropriate file.

Install `mysql-connector-c`

```
$ brew install mysql-connector-c
```

Check it is installed properly

```
$ which mysql
# /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql

$ mysql_config
# Usage: /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Compiler: Clang 10.0.0.10001145
Options:
        --cflags         [-I/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/include/mysql ]
        --cxxflags       [-I/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/include/mysql ]
        --include        [-I/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/include/mysql]
        --libs           [-L/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto]
        --libs_r         [-L/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto]
        --plugindir      [/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib/plugin]
        --socket         [/tmp/mysql.sock]
        --port           [0]
        --version        [5.7.24]
        --libmysqld-libs [-L/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib -lmysqld -lssl -lcrypto]
        --variable=VAR   VAR is one of:
                pkgincludedir [/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/include/mysql]
                pkglibdir     [/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib]
                plugindir     [/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib/plugin]
```

Now install `mysqlclient`

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 0):

For those on MacOS (me on Ventura) using pip requirements.txt file, universal solution is:

```
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" pip install -r requirements.txt
```

where requirements.txt file contains `mysqlclient`, e.g:

```
asgiref==3.7.2
click==8.1.6
Django==4.2.3
mysqlclient==2.2.0
Pillow==10.0.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
svgwrite==1.4.3
```

To make life easier, you can use `pip-compile requirements.in` command, which uses **in** file of flexible content like this:

```
Django>=4.2,<5.0
mysqlclient>=2.2,<3.0
```

and run

```
pip-compile
```

which compiles requirements.txt from requirements.in, pyproject.toml, setup.cfg, or setup.py specs.

And finally do the `LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" pip install -r requirements.txt` command.

One more note, later, if you need to upgrade packages, just run:

```
pip-compile -U
```

Good luck!