# Mysql Import Error with Python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I have met a problem on mysqlclient 1.3.10 after installing libssl1.1

```
import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_mysql.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
```

Reproduce steps:

> - On a ubuntu 14.04 machine
> - Python 2.7.6
>
>   1. echo 'deb http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-10.0.29/repo/ubuntu/
>        trusty main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list
>   2. apt-get -f install --yes --allow-unauthenticated mariadb-server
>   3. Login as root and show default databases successfully
>   4. add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
>   5. apt-get update
>   6. apt-get install
>        libssl-dev(version:1.1.0f-2~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
>   7. pip install mysqlclient
>   8. python -c "import MySQLdb"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587558/error-installing-mysql-python-library-not-found-for-lssl

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to skip this import error.

1. apt-get install python-mysqldb. It will create a _mysql.so at
   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
2. Pip install MySQL-python=1.2.3
3. mv /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_mysql.so /home/
4. cp /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_mysql.so
   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
5. chmod a+x /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_mysql.so

Comment: Another workaround: install mysqlclient using libssl1.0.0 before installing libssl1.1