# I'm trying to install MySql-python in mac 10.13.5

Tags: python, pip, mysql-python

I'm trying to install MySql-python library in mac 10.13.5. But I can't able to install. It throwing an error like

```
_mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
#include "my_config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

could someone give the right solution to install in mac HighSierra

Comment: I hope the information on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765671/install-mysql-python-on-macos-high-sierra) helps

Comment: Thank you, I tried all the methods which they mention in that link. But nothing is working out @kellymandem

Comment: try the solutions in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638444/error-command-cc-failed-with-exit-status-1-mysqldb-installation-on-mac#22633553) then and let me know how that goes

Comment: No, It's not working. I tried everything @kellymandem

Comment: try the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864438/mac-pip-install-mysql-python-unsuccessful), i am sure this might work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac pip install mysql-python unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864438/mac-pip-install-mysql-python-unsuccessful)