# Error loading MySQLdb Module 'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?'

Tags: python, mysql, django, phpmyadmin

I am using windows 10 command line for a django project using python34 however, I am facing difficulties with SQL.

I have already installed mysqlclient using `pip install mysqlclient==1.3.5` and located the file to make sure I was not delusional. I then ran `python manage.py migrate` to migrate the tables to the SQL database (I am using phpmyadmin). However when the command returned with...

```
 File "C:\Users\user\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 30, in <module>
    'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
```

I am aware that questions like these already exist, but not one solution seems to have made any impact on attempts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440230/install-mysql-python-windows   ... check this question also

Answer (score 294, accepted):

```
pip install pymysql
```

Then, edit the __init__.py file in your project origin dir(the same as settings.py)

add:

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this worked for me, I added your code at the top of __init__.py
I wonder why it needed this :(

Comment: In django backend，it use the module named “MySQLdb” as mysql backend. In the function "install_as_MySQLdb()", you can see " sys.modules["MySQLdb"] = sys.modules["_mysql"] = sys.modules["pymysql"] " where pymysql make itself indicate to "MySQLdb" so that django works

Comment: Wish I could give this more than one upvote. This is the only solution that worked for me. thanks!

Comment: Thank you, working well with new and old django and MariaDB :)

Comment: I faced this problem when in recent ArchLinux update, new mariaDB and python 3.7 was upgraded with the latest patch. This solution solves the issue.

Comment: @aforwardz Is there any problem if you deploy including this file?  or is it OK?

Comment: @Ale Just add several lines, that's fine

Comment: ERROR: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.

Comment: @ox. Were you able to get around this?

Comment: @PratikK. Update to newer version of mysqlclient?

Comment: I got the same error as @ox when trying to use the PyMySQL workround (the latest current version of PyMySQL is 0.9.3). I have mysqlclient 1.4.2.post1 installed but django doesn't seem to see it, and PyMySQL 0.9.3 but when I configure django to use that instead of mysqlclient I get the version error.

Comment: @jonah I think my issue may have been that I was trying to run a 2.7 codebase in a 3.7 env

Comment: I used `mysqlclient` instead of `pymysql` as **pymysql** is causing errors.

Comment: mysqlclient also worked for me. And there is no need to put any code in __init__.py, you just need to install the package and change the database connection properties in the settings.py file

Comment: @ox. If you you use macos + homebrew and still see the error –– check your openssl symlinks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006602/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-openssl-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib

Comment: @ox. To fix that issue you'll need to add this line too `pymysql.version_info = (2, 0, 1, 'final', 0)` (use whichever version of `mysqlclient` you want to "fake").

Comment: get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` after adding `pymysql.version_info = (2, 0, 1, 'final', 0)`

Comment: My error output asked me to install `mysqlclient` and such package was not found. I tried `pymysql` and another error raised. Then I installed `cryptography` via `pip` and everything ran ok.

Comment: Now I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'`

Comment: This worked for me.
Thanks for saving me hours and hours of research.

Answer (score 27):

Faced same problem after migrating to python 3. Apparently, MySQL-python is incompatible, so as per official [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers), installed [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) using `pip install mysqlclient` on Mac. Note that there are some OS specific issues mentioned in docs.

Quoting from [docs](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/):

> **Prerequisites**
>
> You may need to install the Python and MySQL development headers and libraries like so:
>
> `sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev` # Debian / Ubuntu
>
> `sudo yum install python-devel mysql-devel` # Red Hat / CentOS
>
> `brew install mysql-connector-c` # macOS (Homebrew) (Currently, it has bug. See below)
>
> On Windows, there are binary wheels you can install without MySQLConnector/C or MSVC.
>
> **Note on Python 3 : if you are using python3 then you need to install python3-dev using the following command :**
>
> `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` # debian / Ubuntu
>
> `sudo yum install python3-devel` # Red Hat / CentOS
>
> **Note about bug of MySQL Connector/C on macOS**
>
> See also: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971
>
> Versions of MySQL Connector/C may have incorrect default configuration options that cause compilation errors when `mysqlclient-python` is installed. (As of November 2017, this is known to be true for homebrew's `mysql-connector-c` and official package)
>
> Modification of `mysql_config` resolves these issues as follows.
>
> Change

```
# on macOS, on or about line 112:
# Create options
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -l "
```

> to

```
# Create options
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

> An improper ssl configuration may also create issues; see, e.g, `brew info openssl` for details on macOS.
>
> **Install from PyPI**
>
> `pip install mysqlclient`
>
> NOTE: Wheels for Windows may be not released with source package. You should pin version in your `requirements.txt` to avoid trying to install newest source package.
>
> **Install from source**
>
> 1. Download source by `git clone` or [zipfile](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/archive/master.zip).
> 2. Customize `site.cfg`
> 3. `python setup.py install`

Comment: this worked. For me who use Ubuntu, simply `sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev` then `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` then `pip install --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --no-binary :all: mysqlclient` and it works.

Comment: @rahmatns you are a savior man...thanks a lot for this comment. Works fine inside my docker container

Answer (score 20):

For pip

```
pip install pymysql
```

For pip3 you should use

```
python3 -m pip install PyMySQL
```

Then, edit the init.py file in your project origin directory (the same as settings.py). Add:

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Comment: This worked for amazon linux 2 but I installed few other packages also.

Comment: In my case doesn' t work with python and but work with python3 thank you!

Answer (score 13):

This command did the trick from @Aniket Sinha's answer above:

`pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: I needed to run `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev python-dev` before this to get it to work.

Answer (score 12):

Use the below command to solve your issue,

```
pip install mysql-python
apt-get install python3-mysqldb libmysqlclient-dev python-dev
```

Works on Debian

Comment: Useless comment. `MySQL-python` lib doesn't support Python 3.x, `mysqlclient` should be proper replacement both for py3 and py2, but, unfortunately, sometimes you get `Did you install mysqlclient?` from Django when `mysqlclient` is already installed. That is the actual question.

Comment: @mega.venik It's not useless, +1 for solving my problem.

Answer (score 11):

If you already have `mysqlclient` installed (i.e. you see `Requirement already satisfied`) and are getting `Error loading MySQLdb Module`, the following worked for me:

1. `pip uninstall mysqlclient`
2. `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"` and `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53653787/6619548)
3. `pip install mysqlclient`

That reinstalls `mysqlclient` and for whatever reason solved my problem.

Comment: Only solution that worked for me out of like 20

Answer (score 3):

For MAC os user:

I have faced this issue many times. The key here is to set these environment variables before installing mysqlclient by pip command. For my case, they are like below:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/protobuf@3.7/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/protobuf@3.7/include"
```

Comment: worked but with a correction: 
`export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib"`
AND
`export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/protobuf/include"`

Answer (score 3):

I am using python 3 in windows.
I also faced this issue. I just uninstalled 'mysqlclient' and then installed it again.
It worked somehow

Comment: Same for Mac OS Sonoma.
pip uninstall mysqlclient
pip install mysqlclient

Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

edit the init.py file in your project origin directory

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing `mysqlclient` using `anaconda` is pretty `simple and straight forward`.

```
conda install -c bioconda mysqlclient
```

and then, install `pymysql` using pip.

```
pip install pymysql
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @elad silver's answer (thanks).

For OSx (Monterey) this worked for me:

1. Install protobuf

```
brew install protobuf
```

2. edit your .bashrc, or .zshenv file with these lines:

```
export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -L/usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS} -I/usr/local/opt/protobuf/include"
```

3. Reinstall `mysqlclient`

```
pip uninstall mysqlclient
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue just recently even with using the python 3 compatible `mysqlclient` library and managed to solve my issue albeit in a bit of an unorthodox manner.  If you are using MySQL 8, give this a try and see if it helps!  :)

I simply made a copy of the `libmysqlclient.21.dylib` file located in my up-to-date installation of MySQL 8.0.13 which is was in `/usr/local/mysql/lib` and moved that copy under the same name to `/usr/lib`.

You will need to temporarily disable security integrity protection on your mac however to do this since you won't have or be able to change permissions to anything in `/usr/lib` without disabling it.  You can do this by booting up into the recovery system, click Utilities on the menu at the top, and open up the terminal and enter `csrutil disable` into the terminal.  Just remember to turn security integrity protection back on when you're done doing this!  The only difference from the above process will be that you run `csrutil enable` instead.

You can find out more about how to disable and enable macOS's security integrity protection [here](https://support.accountek.com/support/solutions/articles/6000101816-odb-1-61d-install-disabling-sip-system-integrity-protection-on-mac-os-el-capitan-10-11-).

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to update my project's dependencies and then restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem run: pip install mysql-connector-python==8.0.23

Faced this issue with mysql.connector version 8.0.24 on mac(if code base is same then the issue should happen in windows as well). [This file](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/django/base.py) on line 51 imports "from django.db.backends.mysql.base import DatabaseWrapper as MySQLDatabaseWrapper".  The [imported file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py) has following code 14-20(exact code and error that you received is part of code

```
try:
    import MySQLdb as Database
except ImportError as err:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
        'Error loading MySQLdb module.\n'
        'Did you install mysqlclient?'
    ) from err
```

The error is formed here. Not sure why this import keeps coming back in different version of mysql connector but 8.0.23 does not have the import, so I reverted to that version and error was gone... This is incase you wish to continue to work with mysql.connector.python. Not sure of logic and why this error is open for last 5 years...

Answer (score 0):

***[NEW]***
Try `pip install mysqlclient`
if not working, and if you are getting below error

> ```
> MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
> ```

Then visit [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) site and download the supported wheel.
Now how to know the supported wheel. For example there are multiple wheel files like below:

mysqlclient-1.4.6-**cp36**-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

See the bold version cp36 which indicates CPython version 3.6
Just install it and this will resolve your issue.

Oh! now if you come across the another problem how to install the wheel file then just refer below line.

```
python -m pip install "C:\Users\Abhijit\Downloads\mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"
```

Comment: This actually solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For now because default mysql server on Debian is MariaDB.

```
user@cl1-preprod ~ % mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 39
```

`apt-get install mariadb` doesn't exist. To install it you need to install this package `apt-get install mariadb-server` but this is only the mysql server the client is also required `apt-get install mariadb-client`.

Then `pip install mysqlclient`

```
user@cl1-preprod ~ % apt-get remove libmysqlclient-dev python-dev
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Le paquet « libmysqlclient-dev » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
Le paquet « python-dev » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
```

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, I ran

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

instead of

```
pip install pymysql
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Run this command in CLI.

```sh
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: Same answer as the one given by Aniket Sinha.