# I have installed the `mysqlclient`, why there still get Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python? issue

Tags: python, django

I have installed the `mysqlclient` in pip3, but I still get this error when I run `uwsgi --ini uwsgi`:

```
*** Operational MODE: threaded ***
django.setup()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 26, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: No module named '_mysql'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myProject/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Python3/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 331, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/Python3/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named '_mysql'.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 21336)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 21338, cores: 20)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 21339)
```

we can see the package in my `site-packages`:

[image]

Why I still get this issue?

---

**EDIT-1**

When I use `python3 manage.py runserver` this works fine.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902357/error-loading-mysqldb-module-did-you-install-mysqlclient-or-mysql-python

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet I have tried those method, not work for me.

Comment: Did you install mysqlclient inside a virtual env ?