# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module

Tags: mysql, django, django-2.0

I am getting the following error when I try and use manage.py after setting up my MySQL database connections in Django 2.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 304, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/sheldon/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-server-xw4tZkRJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

I am working on macOS 10.13.5 and I have installed `mysqlclient` with pipenv (running manage.py in the pipenv environment). I have also installed `mysql-connector-c` with brew as suggested.

Using Sequel Pro I can connect to my MAMP MySQL server without any issues. I have also tried using a docker MySQL server with the same results. I mimicked these settings in settings.php:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'default',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '8889',
    },
}
```

I assume there is something simple I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install mysqlclient?

Comment: Maybe the very first answer will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902357/error-loading-mysqldb-module-did-you-install-mysqlclient-or-mysql-python

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Wow that worked, I could have sworn PyMySQL was a 2.x module only. Much appreciated. I tried my original configuration on my work computer and it worked just fine, do you know why that might be?