# MySQL and Django on Mac - libssl.1.0.0.dylib not loaded

Tags: python, mysql, django

When changing the config to use MySQL as database I'm getting an error trying to start Django server (python manage.py runserver)
It is asking me if I installed mysqlclient which I finally was able to do after some digging around on SO. 
The error it ends with is:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb
>   module.

High up in the Traceback it states that this exception is causing another exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/projectname/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/projectname/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/PycharmProjects/projectname/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/PycharmProjects/projectname/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

There are many questions similar to this and I tried quite a bit but can't seem to get this to work. 
I tried adding MySQLdb as package directly, but then I get the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for MySQLdb

As said; mysqlclient is installed. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902357/error-loading-mysqldb-module-did-you-install-mysqlclient-or-mysql-python) that included an answer that worked for me. Feels like a workaround and not sure if it has any downsides, but this solved the issue.
Copying over the solution for clarity:

```
pip install pymysql
```

Then, edit the __init__.py file in your project origin dir(the same as settings.py)

add:

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```