# Issue for MySQL and Python on installing

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

I am trying to run a Python Django project as required version of 2.7 of Python, Django of 1.8 and MySQL 5.7. While installing the MySQL-python of 1.2.5, building the wheel it's breaking and getting the below error:

```
Building wheel for MySQL-python (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I link the mysql@5.7, so when I check `which mysql_config` I am getting `/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql_config`.

I have tried most of the solutions, I have installed MySQL through brew.

I tried installing mysqlclient in virtual env before Django gets installed, but when I tried installing mysqlclient in venv
I am getting the same error.

```
Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am not able to figure what the issue is, since I am new to Python.

Comment: Probably this might help: https://ruddra.com/posts/install-mysqlclient-macos/ :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ,but didnt worked, i am able to install mysqlclient on outside of virtual env but inside virtual env getting the same error tried installing MySQL-python==1.2.5 also didnt worked same error

Comment: can you please remove the virtual env and create a new one, then try again(if possible)

Comment: i didnt get the error, but when i run the application its throwing the below error 
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 4, 4, 'final', 0)

Comment: when i checked brew list these much things are there, is it because of anything , mysql   mysql-client  mysql-connector-c mysql@5.7  openssl   openssl@1.1

Comment: should i do link and unlik of the mysql@5.7 or mysql. little confused on it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902357/error-loading-mysqldb-module-did-you-install-mysqlclient-or-mysql-python tried this one and now its working . is it correct way.

Thanks rudra for the help very much, was struggling a . lot thank u very much :)

Comment: well django does not support pymysql officially, but if it works out for you then it should be fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201365/discussion-between-dileep-thomas-and-ruddra).