# How to get mysqlclient to work with pipenv?

Tags: mysql, django, pipenv

After installing mysqlclient with 'pipenv install mysqlclient' and attempting to runserver I was getting this error:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error loading MySQLdb Module 'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902357/error-loading-mysqldb-module-did-you-install-mysqlclient-or-mysql-python)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by running 'pipenv shell' to activate virtual environment.