# sudo supervisorctl status: gumi gunicorn ERROR (spawn error)

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu, deployment, gunicorn

```
 $ sudo supervisorctl status
    guni:gunicorn                    FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

Process log details in short:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?

import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

all the packages are installed with their latest versions bit still I am getting these above errors after running `sudo supervisorctl status` output `gumi:gunicorn: ERROR (spawn error)`

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49893339/15353043) it might help to install pymysql with pip:

```
pip install pymysql
```

Then you can edit the **init**.py file of your project origin dir (the same as settings.py) with the following lines:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```