# MySQL issue with XAMPP

Tags: python, django, xampp, mysql-python

I am getting this error on my windows `vscode` terminal after adjusting the database settings on my

`settings.py`

to

`Xampp`

settings in Django:

```
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ExPro\venexp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

I get the error immediately I tried to `run server` which is supposed to run smoothly and prime me to migrate unapplied migrations.. but instead I keep getting the above error no matter what I do.

The settings I implemented on my settings.py before running server is below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'blog',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you install mysqlclient?

Comment: please explain what settings you changed and what exactly broke after that. It is not clear what worked before your change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error loading MySQLdb Module 'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902357/error-loading-mysqldb-module-did-you-install-mysqlclient-or-mysql-python)