# Error while installing mysqlclient in django project

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, mysql-python

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple days.
I am trying to make a django project in a virtual environment and install mysqlclient on it.
Process went like this:
In my project path:

```
virtualenv pyvenv1
```

Then I activated it:

```
source /pyvenv1/bin/activate
```

Then I installed django:

```
pip install django
```

Then I made a new project:

```
django-admin startproject djangop1
```

Then inside that project I try to install mysqlclient

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

I get back this:

```
    Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/daniel/Documents/Python/DjangoP1/py1/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/1h/dg482p2x2bz7n46_px8nphf40000gn/T/pip-install-xgahev5_/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/1h/dg482p2x2bz7n46_px8nphf40000gn/T/pip-wheel-4_cp0769 --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,3,13,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.13 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/_mysql.o
  _mysql.c:257:6: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                          s = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(item);
                            ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:287:6: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                          s = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(item);
                            ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:564:3: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                  _stringsuck(ca, value, ssl);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:553:16: note: expanded from macro '_stringsuck'
          if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);ssl_keepref[n_ssl_keepref++]=t;}\
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:565:3: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                  _stringsuck(capath, value, ssl);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:553:16: note: expanded from macro '_stringsuck'
          if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);ssl_keepref[n_ssl_keepref++]=t;}\
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:566:3: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                  _stringsuck(cert, value, ssl);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:553:16: note: expanded from macro '_stringsuck'
          if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);ssl_keepref[n_ssl_keepref++]=t;}\
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:567:3: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                  _stringsuck(key, value, ssl);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:553:16: note: expanded from macro '_stringsuck'
          if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);ssl_keepref[n_ssl_keepref++]=t;}\
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:568:3: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                  _stringsuck(cipher, value, ssl);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:553:16: note: expanded from macro '_stringsuck'
          if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);ssl_keepref[n_ssl_keepref++]=t;}\
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:2530:8: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
          cname = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(name);
                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  8 warnings generated.
  gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  ld: library not found for -lssl
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/daniel/Documents/Python/DjangoP1/py1/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/1h/dg482p2x2bz7n46_px8nphf40000gn/T/pip-install-xgahev5_/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/1h/dg482p2x2bz7n46_px8nphf40000gn/T/pip-record-fnk1xc7q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/daniel/Documents/Python/DjangoP1/py1/bin/../include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,3,13,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.13 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:257:6: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                            s = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(item);
                              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:287:6: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                            s = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(item);
                              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:564:3: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                    _stringsuck(ca, value, ssl);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:553:16: note: expanded from macro '_stringsuck'
            if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);ssl_keepref[n_ssl_keepref++]=t;}\
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:565:3: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                    _stringsuck(capath, value, ssl);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:553:16: note: expanded from macro '_stringsuck'
            if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);ssl_keepref[n_ssl_keepref++]=t;}\
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:566:3: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                    _stringsuck(cert, value, ssl);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:553:16: note: expanded from macro '_stringsuck'
            if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);ssl_keepref[n_ssl_keepref++]=t;}\
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:567:3: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                    _stringsuck(key, value, ssl);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:553:16: note: expanded from macro '_stringsuck'
            if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);ssl_keepref[n_ssl_keepref++]=t;}\
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:568:3: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                    _stringsuck(cipher, value, ssl);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:553:16: note: expanded from macro '_stringsuck'
            if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);ssl_keepref[n_ssl_keepref++]=t;}\
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:2530:8: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
            cname = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(name);
                  ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    8 warnings generated.
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/daniel/Documents/Python/DjangoP1/py1/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/1h/dg482p2x2bz7n46_px8nphf40000gn/T/pip-install-xgahev5_/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/1h/dg482p2x2bz7n46_px8nphf40000gn/T/pip-record-fnk1xc7q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/daniel/Documents/Python/DjangoP1/py1/bin/../include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1h/dg482p2x2bz7n46_px8nphf40000gn/T/pip-install-xgahev5_/mysqlclient/
```

In the mysqlclient docs, it said that I first need to do:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

Then to edit the mysql_config

I did both.

My $PATH:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I also installed gcc using brew, same error.

I'm pretty lost, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The error is encoded in the line `ld: library not found for -lssl`. Probably you're missing openssl libs; try `brew install openssl` to fix that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing mysql-python: library not found for -lssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587558/error-installing-mysql-python-library-not-found-for-lssl)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql-python%5D+%22library+not+found+for+-lssl%22

Comment: I tried to install openssl and it says it's already installed. HOWEVER, it also told me to set to variables (CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS) and after I did that it worked! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE:

So basically I needed to run these lines for mysqlclient to install:

```
brew install openssl
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
```

Answer (score 1):

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto

if you find above lines then use this command
 `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Answer (score 0):

the error will throw if you are not installed mysql_config, for such case use below command.

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

hope this will solve the problem.