# MySQLdb installed on mac but error "Reason: image not found"

Tags: python, mysql

Im on mac Sierra i have installed MySQLdb for python

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
pip install mysql-python
```

and also following https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm

i have tried to import MySQLdb

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mariadb/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

i have rechecked if MySQLdb was install but heres the msg it shows

```
➜  ~ pip install MySQL-python
Requirement already satisfied: MySQL-python in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: Can this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182294/installing-mysql-python-on-mac-os-x ?

Comment: i installed it then it says pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

Comment: That could be the problem of mysql server. Check once if it is running or not. Try restarting the mysql server once

Comment: something is wrong with mysql installation im getting this error zsh: permission denied: mysql

Comment: did you use sudo @WasifKhalil

Comment: yes i have noticed it works when i use command line or sequel pro, but when i use php application or python it says mysql gone away