# How to solve error while running pip install mysql on Mac( Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name)

Tags: python, django, macos, mysql-python

Already tried re-installing everything. still got this message

```
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
      /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/sl/r5ldvvwx13qbfft41c70zmy80000gn/T/pip-build-env-sflnewt3/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/sl/r5ldvvwx13qbfft41c70zmy80000gn/T/pip-build-env-sflnewt3/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/sl/r5ldvvwx13qbfft41c70zmy80000gn/T/pip-build-env-sflnewt3/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 48, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 27, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate.
This post may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920020/22164538

Also I will suggest using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/get-started/) for modern local development environment.

If you have docker installed create docker-compose.yml file and paste this code into it:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: my-mysql-container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: your_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: your_database_name
      MYSQL_USER: your_username
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: your_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

You can adjust container_name and environment variables to meet your requirements.

Then you can run:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

To start your mysql container, and that is it.
You use *Host: 127.0.0.1* and values you specified in docker-compose.yml to connect to your dockerized mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

for mac, just run

```bash
brew install mysql
```

which helps me.