# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' in macOS 13.4

Tags: python-3.x, macos, mysql-python

when I start the python application in macOS 13.4 with M1 chip, shows error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa/task/refresh_token.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apps.visa.db.visa_sys_config import VisaSysConfig
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa/apps/visa/db/visa_sys_config.py", line 4, in <module>
    from apps.visa.db.base.database_service import Base, session_scope
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa/apps/visa/db/base/database_service.py", line 13, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(url_default, connect_args={'charset':'utf8'})
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 281, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 601, in create_engine
    dbapi = dbapi_meth(**dbapi_args)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 152, in import_dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I have tried to install the mysqlclient:

```
pdm add mysqlclient
pdm add PyMySQL
```

still did not solved the issue. what should I do to fixed this issue in macOS? This is how to connect to database:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from config.config_reader import ConfigReader
from static.visa_sys import visa_logger

Base = declarative_base(class_registry={

})

url_default = ConfigReader.get_value('global', 'conn')
engine = create_engine(url_default, connect_args={'charset':'utf8'})
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    scope_session = Session()
    try:
        yield scope_session
        scope_session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        scope_session.rollback()
        visa_logger.error("session management error", e)
    finally:
        scope_session.close()
```

I also tried like this:

```
> brew install mysql-connector-c
fatal: not in a git directory
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services, skipping update!
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.

Warning: No available formula with the name "homebrew/core/mysql-connector-c".
> pdm add mysql-python
Adding packages to default dependencies: mysql-python
 Lock successful
Changes are written to pyproject.toml.
Synchronizing working set with resolved packages: 1 to add, 0 to update, 0 to remove

  ✖ Install mysql-python 1.2.5 failed
Retry failed jobs
  ✖ Install mysql-python 1.2.5 failed

ERRORS:
add mysql-python failed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/installers/synchronizers.py", line 286, in install_candidate
    self.manager.install(can)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/installers/manager.py", line 33, in install
    installer(str(prepared.build()), self.environment, prepared.direct_url())
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/models/candidates.py", line 414, in build
    self.wheel = Path(builder.build(build_dir, metadata_directory=self._metadata_dir))
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/builders/wheel.py", line 26, in build
    requires = self._hook.get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 166, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 311, in _call_hook
    self._subprocess_runner(
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/builders/base.py", line 261, in subprocess_runner
    return log_subprocessor(cmd, cwd, extra_environ=env)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/builders/base.py", line 107, in log_subprocessor
    raise build_error(e) from None
pdm.exceptions.BuildError: Build backend raised error: Module 'ConfigParser' is missing, please make sure it is specified in the 'build-system.requires' section. If it is not 
possible, add it to the project and use '--no-isolation' option.
Showing the last 10 lines of the build output:
  File "/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pdm-build-env-gbgb_uwn-shared/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
    self.run_setup()
  File "/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pdm-build-env-gbgb_uwn-shared/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
    super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
  File "/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pdm-build-env-gbgb_uwn-shared/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
    exec(code, locals())
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pdm-build-2znutcr3/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

See /var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pdm-install-29_8v4_v.log for detailed debug log.
[InstallationError]: Some package operations are not complete yet
Add '-v' to see the detailed traceback
```

then I also tried to install the configparser:

```
> pdm add configparser
Adding packages to default dependencies: configparser
 Lock successful
Changes are written to pyproject.toml.
Synchronizing working set with resolved packages: 1 to add, 0 to update, 0 to remove

  ✖ Install mysql-python 1.2.5 failed
Retry failed jobs
  ✖ Install mysql-python 1.2.5 failed

ERRORS:
add mysql-python failed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/installers/synchronizers.py", line 286, in install_candidate
    self.manager.install(can)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/installers/manager.py", line 33, in install
    installer(str(prepared.build()), self.environment, prepared.direct_url())
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/models/candidates.py", line 414, in build
    self.wheel = Path(builder.build(build_dir, metadata_directory=self._metadata_dir))
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/builders/wheel.py", line 26, in build
    requires = self._hook.get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 166, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 311, in _call_hook
    self._subprocess_runner(
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/builders/base.py", line 261, in subprocess_runner
    return log_subprocessor(cmd, cwd, extra_environ=env)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/pdm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdm/builders/base.py", line 107, in log_subprocessor
    raise build_error(e) from None
pdm.exceptions.BuildError: Build backend raised error: Module 'ConfigParser' is missing, please make sure it is specified in the 'build-system.requires' section. If it is not 
possible, add it to the project and use '--no-isolation' option.
Showing the last 10 lines of the build output:
  File "/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pdm-build-env-xzqelo2w-shared/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
    self.run_setup()
  File "/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pdm-build-env-xzqelo2w-shared/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
    super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
  File "/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pdm-build-env-xzqelo2w-shared/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
    exec(code, locals())
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pdm-build-d8frbils/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

See /var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pdm-install-p7y6lsg0.log for detailed debug log.
[InstallationError]: Some package operations are not complete yet
Add '-v' to see the detailed traceback
```

Comment: i think you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182294/installing-mysql-python-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I tried these answer seems did not work.